# why not restrict codomain?

Tags: general-topology

I have some confusion regarding restriction of function

In wikipedia it is written that

Restriction of function

let $f : E \rightarrow F$ be  a  function from a set $E$ to a set  $F$. If a set $A$ is  a subset  of $E$ , then  the restriction  of  $f$ to $ A$ is the function $f|_{A}: A \to F$

Here it's only restrict  domain part   , why  not restrict  codomain ?

**My thinking** :

Suppose  $B \subset  F$, then the restriction  of  $f$ to $ A$ is the function $f|_{A}: A \to B$

Is this statement is true/false ?

Comment: No it is false because there is the possibility $f(x)\not \in B$ for some $x\in A$. For this reason one define the inclusion such that the codomain  is always $F$, or at least the image $f(A)$.

Comment: okss  got  its @FedericoFallucca  that mean my statement is valid only  when $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphism

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Your domain and codomain are topological spaces? And what do you mean when you say ‘$A$ and $B$ are homeomorphism?’

Comment: @FedericoFallucca i have tag general topology...u should think that why  i have tag.....yes  it is topological space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definition doesn't always work. For example, if we have $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined as $f(x)=x^2$, we couldn't restrict the codomain to $(0,+\infty)$, since we'd miss $f(0)=0$. Remember a function $f:A\to B$ takes elements $a\in A$ and give us elements $f(a)=b\in B$ in return.

The restriction of a function on a subset $A$ of the domain is different, since the function is already defined in a bigger set (the domain), the only thing to worry about is to only take the elements of the domain that are also in $A$, whose images were already in the codomain.

In general, you can define a function $f$ on a set $A$ as you please, taking each element of $A$ and deciding where to map it, but then you need to make sure your codomain B contains all images, or otherwise the notation $f:A\to B$ wouldn't make much sense. For example, if I want to define $f$ on $[0,1]$ as the constant map giving $1$, I can define $f:[0,1]\to\{1\}$, or $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb [0,1]$, or $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ (note that they are different maps; the first one is onto for instance), but I cannot define $f:[0,1]\to\{0\}$, since I need $1$ to be in the codomain.

Answer (score 2):

For instance $A=\lbrace 0,1\rbrace\subseteq E=\lbrace 0,1,2\rbrace$ and $f:E\rightarrow F=\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=f(2)=1$. In this example, the restriction on codomain is $F$ itself.